# Files are disappearing from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, amazon-cloudtrail

I am having files just disappear from Amazon S3 without a trace.
The following is turned on with the bucket concerned:

- Versoning
- Server Access Logging
- Object-Level Logging

There is absolutely no logs about deletes either from within AWS or our own application (We log all activity there as well).

Permissions are locked down and files only accessable via Cloudfront.

Also, there is no versioning of the missing files so I can't even restore them. This issue has happened twice now in the last month and I am at a total loss as to what is happening.

As there are no deleteObject logs there must be something else that is happening here and I dont know what.

Any help or insight would be of great help?

Comment: Any lifesycles policies?

Comment: No, none in place.

Comment: Without a lifecycle policy or any access logs pointing to a DELETE operation, I'd say your best bet is the AWS support. Objects in S3 are replicated transparently so I doubt it's data loss on AWS side as well.